# Macros in MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

For data analysis purposes, i'm often doing very similar queries where i aggregate data along various dimensions. Dimensions i use always change but the fields i'm aggregating are always the same. In practice, i'm doing

```
select key1, key2, ... 
       sum(agg_field1), avg(agg_field2), count(distinct agg_field3) ...
from ...
where ...
```

I have a lot of aggregations and it would be very handful if i could replace the list of aggregations by some kind of macros. I use the word "macro" since it reminds me C/C++ macros. I was imagining:

```
select key1, key2, ..., MY_AGGREGATIONS
from ...
where ...
```

This would have a lot of advantages

- Queries would me more clear
- It would be easy to share those aggregations to other users on the same db
- Queries would be faster to write

Comment: So how would the magic `MY_AGGREGATIONS` know which columns to aggregate? Your SQL client might have such a feature, but I don't think this makes sense on the server

Comment: Nothing magic, i would have defined it somewhere like a stored procedure. Having this feature on the server would allow every user to use that macro

Answer (score 0):

You can develop one function  where you can pass parameter and using while loop you can construct query dynamically. if you want to execute that query also then you can develop store procedure where you and prepare query dynamically and execute it.

You can pass parameter with information like how many aggregation field you want and distict keyword need with any of it.
then you can use while loop and construct your query.

By prepare statement you can execute dynamic queries
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html